# Optional Path React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do I match an optional path using the `Route` component in React Router 4?

For example I have an `Orders` component that I want to render on both /account and /account/orders.

The equivalent would be having two Route components to match both paths.

`<Route exact path="/account" component={Orders} />`

`<Route exact path="/account/orders" component={Orders} />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can do the following to match both paths:

`<Route exact path="/account/(orders)?" component={Orders} />`

Comment: it's better to put slash inside of parentheses: ```<Route exact path="/account(/orders)?" component={Orders} />```

Answer (score 8):

You can use path param optional on **react-router 4** like that:

```
<Route exact path="/account" component={Orders} />

<Route exact path="/account/orders?" component={Orders} />
```

So to define a parameter as optional you add a trailing question-mark (?). Also for multiple optional parameters:

```
<Route path="/account/:pathParam1?/:pathParam2?" component={Orders} />
```

Comment: Please make sure That your index.html files includes the bundle.js as  `<script src="/bundle.js" /> not <script src="bundle.js" />`
If not, your route with optional param will not load the component

Comment: How does it distinguish between the optional params? Like say you `:pathParam2` being present, does not depend on `:pathParam1` being present and vice versa